# X-Frame-Options Wordpress Azure Website duplicated

Tags: wordpress, azure

I am trying to secure my website further so i added an `X-Frame Option` to `SAMEORIGIN` in my web.config folder in azure but when i run a scan i get the following:

```
X-Frame-Options (XFO) headers were found, a response with multiple XFO header entries may not be predictably treated by all user-agents.
```

And i found that my `wp-admin` is the cause of it

[image]

Is there anyway i can edit web.config file of `wp-admin`, i couldn't seem to find any other `web.config` files in my root just the one. Any idea how i can remove one of the `X-Frame Options`?